# Is it possible to get validation attributes from all properties and show them to the user if there is a violation?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, reflection, data-annotations

I generate my views genericly with reflection so I am wondering if it is possible to get the validation attributes for all the properties of a class and then make them show in the view if there is a violation

For example:

```
public class Person 
{
    [Range(0,300)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage ="Please provide a weight")]
    public double Weight { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your query - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027613/how-to-retrieve-data-annotations-from-code-programmatically

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Sadly, this answers only part of my query, I'm also wondering how I could display the error near the specific input field value, do you have any links on that? :-)

Comment: Take a look at this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/18965540
If this is not working out, will take a look at implementing something custom.